# I tried to install ionic but it returns : npm ERR! code E418

Tags: ionic-framework, npm

I have a serious problem. I tried to install ionic, cordova, angular, react-native-cli, https-status-error and other packages and it always returns:

```
npm ERR! code E418
npm ERR! 418 I'm a teapot: ionic @ latest
```

Please note that it may be wrong and I do not understand what is happening. It was fine until 3 days ago.

Comment: what command do you type and what response do you get?

Comment: I've just started seeing the same thing. Fine until today.

Comment: This would be related https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20791

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we have to add proxy information in .npmrc file with userid and password. You will not find any issues. Recently people are getting http 418 - tea pot issues. That we can fix setting up registry with https like below

## USE THIS:

proxy=http://<>:<>@<>:8080/

https-proxy=http://<>:<>@<>:8080/

registry=https://registry.npmjs.org

Comment: proxy=http://<<userid>>:<<password>>@<<proxy>>:8080/

https-proxy=http://<<userid>>:<<password>>@<<proxy>>:8080/

registry=https://registry.npmjs.org

Answer (score 10):

So, post may 29th '18, this is the common error being faced worldwide by devs working behind corporate proxies. The following tweak fixed the issue for me:

1. Go to your .npmrc file.

   you'll have the following similar content in the file depending upon the configs you are setting up-

   ```
   strict-ssl=false
   registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
   python=C:/Python27/python.exe
   msvs_version=2015
   http-proxy=<WHATEVER-PROXY-YOU-USUALLY-ADD>:8000
   ```

Note: Ignore the extra configs like python variable path.

2. Update the registry link to '**https://registry.npmjs.org/**'. So your file would look like this now-

   ```
    strict-ssl=false
    registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
    python=C:/Python27/python.exe
    msvs_version=2015
    http-proxy=<WHATEVER-PROXY-YOU-USUALLY-ADD>:8000
   ```
3. And Viola! you are all set to fire your npm install commands :)

Comment: This works for me. Changing http to https in the registry. Could someone please explain why ?

Answer (score 4):

Work for me!

If you set proxy should be unset.

```
npm config delete proxy
npm config delete https-proxy
```

Solution resolve npm ^___^

```
npm cache clean --force
npm cache verify
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the very same issue and managed to fix it. 
In my case, I initially had the value of "**http**://registry.npmjs.org/" and changed it to "**https**". Below are the set of commands I ran:

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
npm cache clean --force
npm cache verify

npm install
```

Comment: Yup that's the key step - `http` used to be tolerated, but now it has to be `https`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you behind a coorporate proxy? I was facing the same error when I tried to run `npm install`. What I did was to remove the proxy configuration from NPM, like so:

```
npm config rm proxy

npm config rm https-proxy
```

That did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

> 418 I’m a teapot: This code was defined in 1998 as one of the traditional IETF April Fools’ jokes, in RFC 2324, Hyper Text Coffee Pot Control Protocol, and is not expected to be implemented by actual HTTP servers.

However, we know at least one implementation does exist now.

It's a bug or weird joke.

As @TomLingham suggested, follow https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20791 to watch progress resolving the issue and for some workarounds.

For example `yarn` still healthy.

Answer (score 1):

After visiting many sites and testing everything i found,
This Solution finally worked for me. If you are using Windows,

1. Click windows button and type "run"
2. Type `.npmrc` and open this file using your favorite editor.
3. Replace "registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/" with "registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/" and save.

**Note:** If you have any proxy issues too..you can set your proxy like below in the same file. In my case i have a **special symbol "@"** in my password.
When i tried changing proxy using **npm config set proxy** command these special characters got converted to something else :) So you could eliminate all these headaches if you set your proxy along in this file directly.

Your final `.npmrc` should look like below. you could remove proxy lines if you do not have any issues with proxy and do not forget to replace the port in below example with your proxy port.

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/  
proxy=http://username:password@yourproxy.net:8080/   
https-proxy=http://username:password@yourproxy.net:8080/  
strict-ssl=false
```

Answer (score 0):

I too ran into the same problem today, It looks like we all are in the same boat.
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20791. Some solutions are provided in the link. You might want to look into it if it is a pressing issue.